# $\aleph_0^c=2^c$

Tags: real-analysis, infinity

Problem: Prove that $\aleph_0^c=2^c$

My attempt: $\aleph_0^c=\aleph_0^{2^{\aleph_0}}=\aleph_0^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$

Then $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}=2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$, so $\aleph_0^c=2^c$.

But my intuition is telling me I may have made a mistake or an assumption that I can't make. Did I mess up? Or is this a valid proof?

Comment: You seem to believe that $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{n+1}$ (at least for $n=1,2$). That's an instance of the generalized continuum hypothesis, which is not provable in ZFC.

Comment: Ok. So if I get to assume $2^{\aleph_0}=c$, $\aleph_0*\aleph_0=\aleph_0$, and $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, do I have enough to solve this? What's confusing me is that if $\aleph_0*\aleph_0=\aleph_0$, then why doesn't $\aleph_0^c=\aleph_0*\aleph_0*\dots=\aleph_0$?

Comment: Because $\aleph_0*\aleph_0*\ldots$ isn't $c$ many factors of $\aleph_0$, it's only $\aleph_0$ many factors of $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Would $2^c=3^c$?

Comment: 2^aleph_0 = the continuum is often the *definition* of the continuum ("c"), so there is no need to "assume" it. On the other hand, as Andreas Blass said, it cannot be proved in ZFC that 2^aleph_0  =  aleph_1. (I can recommend the book "Theory of Sets" by E. Kamke.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $2^c \le \aleph_0^c$. For the other direction, it may be helpful to consider $2^c$ to be the (cardinality of the) set of functions $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, and similarly $\aleph_0^c$ to be the cardinality of the set of functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Try and contruct a surjection from the former into the latter (hint: use binary expansions).

Comment: Thanks, I think I was able to get it. Infinity isn't easy!

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem tells:

> Assume $A, B$ are two groups, if there is an injective function from $A$ to $B$ and an injective function from $B$ to $A$, then the cardinality of $A$ and $B$ equals.

This theorem is not very easy to prove. If you know this theorem, by using it we can prove this way:

I will prove $\mathbb N ^c = 2^c$. the injection from $2^c$ to $\mathbb N ^c$ is easy to construct. I only give the construction of injection from $\mathbb N ^c$ to $2^c$.

Focus on this function
$$f(x) = \tan\left(\pi x - \frac{\pi}2\right)$$

It is a bijective function from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb R$. We define the map $\mathbb N^{\mathbb R} \rightarrow \mathbb N^{(0,1)}$ by mapping $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb N$ to $g \circ f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb N$. You can check that it is a bijection. Hence we now only need to construct an injective map from $N^{(0,1)}$ to $2^c$.

Now assume $h \in N^{(0,1)}$ is a function, we define a map $\mathcal F: N^{(0,1)} \rightarrow 2^c$ by mapping $h$ to
$$\mathcal F(h): x \rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x \in \mathbb Z\text{ or } x<0 \\
\lceil x \rceil \text{th digital of binary number of } h(x-\lfloor x \rfloor) & \text{if } x \in [0,\infty) - \mathbb N 
\end{cases}
$$

You can check that $\mathcal F$ is an injection. Hence we can use the previous theorem to complete our proof.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I did following Inbo's hint. Wish I could accept both!